# Only 1 checkbox can be checked? PHP

Tags: php, checkbox

I'm having an issue with checkboxes. I can check both checkboxes, but after submitting, only 1 checkbox is checked. I want them to both be checked after submitting.

[image]

Why are they not both checked after submit? What's going wrong in the process?

```
<?php
$id = $_GET["id"];
$stmt = $dbConnection->prepare('SELECT * FROM paginas WHERE id = ?');
$stmt->bind_param('s', $id);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        ?>
        <a href="javascript:;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#terugnaarpaginas" class="h1url">Terugkeren naar mijn pagina's</a>
        <h1>Wijzig pagina: <?php echo $row["name"]; ?></h1>
        <?php
        if(isset($_POST["opslaan"])) {
            if(empty($_POST["heading"])) {
                echo '<p class="error">Titel kan niet leeg zijn</p>';
            } elseif(empty($_POST["content"])) {
                echo '<p class="error">Content kan niet leeg zijn</p>';
            } else {
                $heading = $_POST["heading"];
                $content = $_POST["content"];
                $updated = date("d-m-Y H:i:s");
                $id = $row["id"];
                $public = $_POST["public"];
                $menu = $_POST["menu"];
                $stmt = $dbConnection->prepare('UPDATE paginas SET heading = ?, content = ?, updated = ?, public = ?, menu = ? WHERE id = ?');
                $stmt->bind_param('ssssss', $heading, $content, $updated, $public, $menu, $id);
                $stmt->execute();

                echo '<p class="success">Wijzigingen zijn succesvol opgeslagen. <a href="">Bekijken</a></p>';
            }
        } else {
?>
<form method="POST" action="">
    <input type="text" name="heading" id="fulltext" placeholder="Titel" value="<?php echo $row["heading"]; ?>">
    <textarea id="fullbox" class="editor" name="content"><?php echo $row["content"]; ?></textarea>
    <div class="pad"><input type="checkbox" name="public" id="public" value="<?php
    if($row["public"] == "1") {
        echo '0';
    } else {
        echo '1';
    }
    ?>" <?php
    if($row["public"] == "1") {
        echo ' checked';
    } else {
        echo '';
    }
    ?>><label for="public" class="checker">Gepubliceerd</label><input type="checkbox" name="menu" id="menu" value="<?php
    if($row["menu"] == "1") {
        echo '0';
    } else {
        echo '1';
    }
    ?>" <?php
    if($row["menu"] == "1") {
        echo ' checked';
    } else {
        echo '';
    }
    ?>><label for="menu" class="checker">Menu</label></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <p id="left">Laatst gewijzigd: <?php echo $row["updated"]; ?></p><input type="submit" value="Bewaar wijzigingen" name="opslaan" class="nomp">
    <div class="clear"></div>
</form>
<?php
        }
    }
} else {
    echo '<p>Deze pagina bestaat niet.</p>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `value` of the checkbox should always be `1` instead of the condition you have there, and when preparing to put it in the database you should do:

```
$public = isset($_POST['public']) ? 1 : 0;
```

Otherwise, you will be submitting the value `0` every other time, which will turn the value off even if you checked the box.

Comment: Correct. If a checkbox is checked, it will send whatever `value` you give it. If it is not checked, then it won't be sent at all. So you should use `isset()` to check its presence. In most cases you don't need a `value` on a checkbox at all, but I like having one just to be "safe".

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Niet the Dark Absol's answer above you should create dynamic names for each element or use `name="public[]` to capture all selected values.

Answer (score 0):

You must set your input name with `[]` after the name. like `check_list[]`.

For example:

```
<form action="test.php" method="post">
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="value 1">
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="value 2">
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="value 3">
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="value 4">
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="value 5">
<input type="submit" />
</form>
<?php
if(!empty($_POST['check_list'])) {
    foreach($_POST['check_list'] as $check) {
            echo $check; //echoes the value set in the HTML form for each checked checkbox.
                         //so, if I were to check 1, 3, and 5 it would echo value 1, value 3, value 5.
                         //in your case, it would echo whatever $row['Report ID'] is equivalent to.
    }
}
?>
```